# Record type in Content Version Object

Tags: picklist, profile, record-type, contentversion

I have a picklist in the Content Version object and I have a set of profiles. The values of the picklist must be restricted to each profile that is the values seen by one profile should not be seen by the other profiles.

This can be done using record types but I did not find any documentation on record types for Content Version. Can we create record types for Content Version document?

If not, any way to do this other than validation? No validation because the picklist values will visible to all the profiles

Comment: Again, it's the picklist values and not the picklist field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From spring 15 salesforce files support record types:

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_chatter_files_record_types.htm

You can use salesforce files for creating record types. The record types defined insided the salesforce files are being used by the content version, and you can do your configuration with these record types.

Comment: You saved me! Wish I could give more than 1 upvote! Thanks! :)

Comment: happy to help :)